# When using @-ms-viewport to handle all screen resolutions in a Windows 8 app, does it matter whether I scale down or scale up?

Tags: css, windows-8

I'm creating my first Windows 8 app using JavaScript / CSS / HTML and have developed my application based on the 1920 x 1080 native resolution on my system. I've then put the following into my css:

```
@-ms-viewport {
   width: 1920px;
   height: 1080px;
}
```

This seems to work ok in the simulator at various resolutions, as it scales everything down for 1024x768 for example. I'm just wondering if I'm going about this the right way though. Should I perhaps instead be designing my app for 1024x768 and scaling up instead? Does it matter?